# jQuery scroll down ball

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how to scroll down a "ball" which contains some text.

I wrote code for the JavaScript to get the "ball" to scroll down as the page was scrolling.

```
$(".scrollDown").click(function() {
    $("html body").animate({ scrollTop: 280}, 1300);
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.ball-about {   
position: fixed;  
top: 280px;  
left: 30px;  
display: block;     
background: #809dbf;  
border-radius: 50%; 
height: 150px;  
width:    150px; 
margin: 0;

}
```

Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-color-2 scrollDown">About</a>
<div class="ball-about pull-left"><h2>About</h2>
```

The problem is, this WORKS, BUT, there's a but... If the ball is in the position "fixed", it follows along as the page scrolls down. But what I want, is that when I scroll down "280px" as I want in the JavaScript, if I keep scrolling, the ball just follows until the page ends. How can I set so the ball only scrolls 280px and then stops right there? Sorry if I'm not clear with what I'm trying to explain... Can I set a MAX scroll height? So it just scrolls 280px?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

Remove the `position` from the CSS.

Then, in your script, add in the styles on the `click`.

So

```
$(".scrollDown").click(function() {
    $("html body").animate({ scrollTop: 280}, 1300);
    var styles = {
      position : "absolute",
      top : "280px"
    };
    $('.ball-about').css(styles);
});
```

Here's a **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/aHKJk/

Comment: Altough, I changed $('.ball-about').css(styles); to animate instead. Worked out better for some reason, I wanted the ball to have a "animation" as well. But thanks!